# Gradle task that changes behavior of another one

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

Can you please help me to configure two checkstyle tasks that either fail build or ignore errors? Unfortunately, I don't have enough knowledge to do it myself.

I have checkstyle configuration

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = "7.1.1"
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
    ignoreFailures = true
    showViolations = true
    reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/checkstyleReports")
    configFile = file("$rootDir/gradle/checkstyle.xml")
    configProperties = ['baseDir': "$project.projectDir"]
}
```

Checkstyle plugin adds another tasks: checkstyleMain, checkstyleTest.

**I need to create new task that extends checkstyleMain but override property *ignoreFailures***

I see it in the next way(but it doesn't work):

```
checkstyleMain {
    ignoreFailures = true
}

task forceCheckstyleMain(type: Checkstyle) {
    ignoreFailures = false
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to extend the task or override it?

Comment: I thought that override is possible only after extending.
The main idea: I need new task that run checkstyleMain with ignoreFailures = false.
I want to have two tasks for checkstyle: first ignore failures and second fail build on any checkstyle violation

Comment: Mh it should work with the code you showed. Is there any error shown or whats the outcome?

Comment: **gradle clean checkstyleMain** runs compileJava, classes, jar, etc.. tasks.
But **gradle clean forceCheckstyleMain** runs only clean and then it shows that forceCheckstyleMain is up-to-date.
`:my-project:forceCheckstyleMain  UP-TO-DATE`
so it seems that forceCheckstyleMain doesn't do anything(compiling, checkstyle checks, etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see full discussing thread with other ideas here https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-task-that-changes-behavior-of-another-one/20295/7

To answer on my question it can be resolved in the next way

```
checkstyleMain {
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
        ignoreFailures = !graph.hasTask(":" + project.name + ":forceCheckstyleMain")
    }
}

task forceCheckstyleMain(dependsOn: 'checkstyleMain') {
}
```

maybe it isn't the best solution, but it's short and it works